# How can I copy n lines after the last 2 occurences of a string in a file?

Tags: text-processing, grep, tail

Is there a way to copy the first n (say 3) lines after the last 2 occurrences of a string are found in a file? 
When I was only interested in those after the last occurence, I used:

```
grep -A4 'stringhere' filein.txt | tail -n 3 >> fileout.txt
```

However, I don't know how to rewrite this command to carry out the task for the last two occurrences of the string.

i.e. For an input file containing:

```
Text 1  
Text 2  
Text 3  
Text 4  
STRINGIMLOOKINGFOR  
Text 5  
Text 6  
Text 7  
Text 8  
Text 9  
STRINGIMLOOKINGFOR  
Text 10  
Text 11  
Text 12  
Text 13  
Text 14  
STRINGIMLOOKINGFOR  
Text 15  
Text 16  
Text 17  
Text 18  
Text 19
```

I would like the output (for n=3)to be:

```
Text 10  
Text 11  
Text 12  
Text 15  
Text 16  
Text 17
```

Comment: Where does the "Thanks in advance!" in the output come from?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. That was me saying thanks in advance to whoever replied. Not in the output.

Comment: That doesn't belong in a question at all. If you want to thanks someone upvote their answer.

Comment: Ok. This was my first question on the site. I didn't know that's how it works but I will do that.

Comment: why did you post 6 lines for condition `for n=3` ?

Comment: Because text lines 10,11,12 are after the second-to-last occurrence and text lines 15,16,17 are after the last occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
s="STRINGIMLOOKINGFOR"
grep -Poz "$s"'.*(\n.*){3}' file | grep -v "$s" | tail -n 6
```

```
Text 10  
Text 11  
Text 12  
Text 15  
Text 16  
Text 17
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/^PATT$/{for(i=3;i;--i){getline;print}}' file|tail -n6
```

With above, we are looking the whole lines match with pattern `PATT`, then using `getline` to `print` next 3 lines after that and do the `tail -n6` to get last 6 lines which are for last 2 occurences of your pattern.

Using `grep`

```
grep -A3 --no-group-separator '^PATT$' file |grep -v "PATT" |tail -n6
```

With above, we are looking for the same as above and print out `-A3` next 3 lines **A**fter matched pattern `PATT` found, then exclude lines with `PATT` itself from the result and do the tail as same.

The [`--no-group-separator`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Context-Line-Control.html) is used to *grep* don't print separator between each group of matches.

Comment: @downvoter I will happy to see the reason of your vote, down vote without explanation will help no one!

Answer (score 0):

ugly, but I think I'm getting the output you wanted?

```
export n=3
grep -A$n STRINGIMLOOKINGFOR filein.txt | grep -v "^-" | grep -v STRINGIMLOOKINGFOR | tail -`expr $n \* 2`
```